# Cumulative grade-point-average calculator in C++

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple Cumulative [grade-point-average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grading_in_education) calculator in C++, and would like to ask for advices to improve the code in terms of best practices (efficiency, reliability) in the language. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Subject
{
    public:
        std::string name;
        unsigned creditHour, mark;

        Subject(const std::string& name, unsigned creditHour, unsigned mark)
        : name(name), creditHour(creditHour), mark(mark)
        {} 
};

class CGPACalculator
{
    public:
        unsigned getGradePointWith(unsigned mark)
        {
            if (mark <= 100 && mark > 90) return 10;
            if (mark <= 90 && mark > 80) return 9;
            if (mark <= 80 && mark > 70) return 8;
            if (mark <= 70 && mark > 60) return 7;
            if (mark <= 60 && mark > 50) return 6;
            if (mark <= 50 && mark > 40) return 5;
            if (mark <= 40 && mark > 30) return 4;
            return 0;
        }

        double calculateCGPAWith(double gradePointsSum, unsigned numOfSubjects)
        {
            return gradePointsSum / numOfSubjects;
        }
};

class CGPAPrinter
{
    public:
        void printSubjectsSummary(std::vector<Subject*> subjects)
        {
            for(Subject* s : subjects)
            {
                std::cout << "Subject:\t" << s->name << "\t\t";
                std::cout << "Credit Hours:\t" << s->creditHour << "\t\t";
                std::cout << "Mark:\t" << s->mark << std::endl;
            }
        }

        void printCGPA(double cgpa)
        {
            std::cout << "Your CGPA is: " << cgpa << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::string subjectName;
    unsigned creditHour, mark, numOfSubjects;
    double gradePointsSum = 0;
    std::vector<Subject*> subjects;
    CGPACalculator calculator;
    CGPAPrinter printer;

    // Get input from user
    std::cout << "Enter number of subjects: \t";
    std::cin >> numOfSubjects;

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfSubjects; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter subject name: \t";
        std::cin >> subjectName;

        std::cout << "Enter credit hours: \t";
        std::cin >> creditHour;

        std::cout << "Enter mark: \t";
        std::cin >> mark;
        
        gradePointsSum += calculator.getGradePointWith(mark);

        Subject *s = new Subject(subjectName, creditHour, mark);
        subjects.push_back(s);
    }

    printer.printSubjectsSummary(subjects);
    printer.printCGPA(calculator.calculateCGPAWith(gradePointsSum, numOfSubjects));

    return 0;
}
```

Appreciate your valuable feedbacks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### C vs C++ headers

> ```
>    #include <stdio.h>
> ```

This is a C header. For C++ we'd want `#include <cstdio>` instead (which puts the contents in the `std::` namespace). Though it looks like we're not using anything from this header anyway.

---

### Aggregate initialization

> ```
> class Subject
> {
> public:
>   std::string name;
>   unsigned creditHour, mark;
>
>   Subject(const std::string &name, unsigned creditHour, unsigned mark)
>       : name(name), creditHour(creditHour), mark(mark)
>   {
>   }
> };
> ```

In modern C++ we don't need to add a constructor just to initialize member variables like this. We can write this as a simple `struct`, and use [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
struct Subject
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned creditHour, mark;
};

    ...

    Subject *s = new Subject{ subjectName, creditHour, mark };
```

---

### Classes vs free functions

> ```
> class CGPACalculator
> {
> public:
>   unsigned getGradePointWith(unsigned mark)
>   {
>       if (mark <= 100 && mark > 90)
>           return 10;
>       if (mark <= 90 && mark > 80)
>           return 9;
>       if (mark <= 80 && mark > 70)
>           return 8;
>       if (mark <= 70 && mark > 60)
>           return 7;
>       if (mark <= 60 && mark > 50)
>           return 6;
>       if (mark <= 50 && mark > 40)
>           return 5;
>       if (mark <= 40 && mark > 30)
>           return 4;
>       return 0;
>   }
>
>   double calculateCGPAWith(double gradePointsSum, unsigned numOfSubjects)
>   {
>       return gradePointsSum / numOfSubjects;
>   }
> };
> ```

This class has no state (i.e. contains no member variables), so it should not be a class. This also applies to the `CGPAPrinter` class. We can use a `namespace` to group related functions instead of a class:

```
namespace GPA
{

    struct Subject
    {
        std::string name;
        unsigned creditHour, mark;
    };

    unsigned getGradePointWith(unsigned mark) { ... }

    double calculateCGPAWith(double gradePointsSum, unsigned numOfSubjects) { ... }

    void printSubjectsSummary(std::vector<Subject *> subjects) { ... }

    void printCGPA(double cgpa) { ... }

} // GPA
```

Now we don't need to create any unnecessary objects. We can just call the functions we need.

---

### Variable declaration

> ```
> int main()
> {
>   std::string subjectName;
>   unsigned creditHour, mark, numOfSubjects;
>   double gradePointsSum = 0;
>   std::vector<Subject *> subjects;
> ```

Declaring all variables at the top of a scope is an obsolete and unnecessary habit from ancient C. We should instead declare variables where they are first needed, initialize them to useful values, and avoid reusing them where practical. Something like:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter number of subjects: \t";
    unsigned numOfSubjects;
    std::cin >> numOfSubjects;
    
    std::vector<Subject *> subjects;
    double gradePointsSum = 0.0;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numOfSubjects; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter subject name: \t";
        std::string subjectName;
        std::cin >> subjectName;

        std::cout << "Enter credit hours: \t";
        unsigned creditHour;
        std::cin >> creditHour;

        std::cout << "Enter mark: \t";
        unsigned mark;
        std::cin >> mark;

        gradePointsSum += GPA::getGradePointWith(mark);

        Subject *s = new Subject{ subjectName, creditHour, mark };
        subjects.push_back(s);
    }

    GPA::printSubjectsSummary(subjects);
    GPA::printCGPA(GPA::calculateCGPAWith(gradePointsSum, numOfSubjects));

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Memory management

> ```
> std::vector<Subject *> subjects;
> ...
>     Subject *s = new Subject{ subjectName, creditHour, mark };
> ```

If we use `new` to allocate memory we must ensure we clean it up again by calling `delete` (to avoid leaking memory). We should generally avoid manual memory management and use a smart pointer (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`) instead.

However, in this case it's unnecessary. We can simply store the subjects by value:

```
std::vector<Subject> subjects;
    ...
    subjects.emplace_back(subjectName, creditHour, mark);
```

---

### User input

> ```
> std::cout << "Enter number of subjects: \t";
> unsigned numOfSubjects;
> std::cin >> numOfSubjects;
> ```

We should add some error checking to ensure that the user actually entered a number, and that we successfully read it.

---

### Aside

Contrary to the other answer, I actually don't mind the series of `if` statements in:

> ```
>     unsigned getGradePointWith(unsigned mark)
>     {
>         if (mark <= 100 && mark > 90) return 10;
>         if (mark <= 90 && mark > 80) return 9;
>         if (mark <= 80 && mark > 70) return 8;
>         if (mark <= 70 && mark > 60) return 7;
>         if (mark <= 60 && mark > 50) return 6;
>         if (mark <= 50 && mark > 40) return 5;
>         if (mark <= 40 && mark > 30) return 4;
>         return 0;
>     }
> ```

But, we could make it simpler by only checking one bound (since we're checking in descending order):

```
unsigned getGradePointWith(unsigned mark)
{
    if (mark > 100) return 0; // todo: output an error!??
    if (mark >= 91) return 10;
    if (mark >= 81) return 9;
    if (mark >= 71) return 8;
    if (mark >= 61) return 7;
    if (mark >= 51) return 6;
    if (mark >= 41) return 5;
    if (mark >= 31) return 4;
    return 0;
}
```

It's much easier to glance at this and understand the grade boundaries than it is to understand the nuances of a math equation.

Comment: Why use a vector of pointers?  The `std::vector` also works with local variables, as it would make a copy when using the `push_back()` method.

Answer (score 8):

## truncated division

```
            if (mark <= 40 && mark > 30) return 4;
```

A mathematician would write that as `30 < mark ≤ 40`.
At least when using a left-to-right writing system,
since we conventionally picture the (positive) real number line
starting at the left and extending rightwards.
In C, prefer to phrase it as

```
            if (30 < mark && mark <= 40) return 4;
```

`getGradePointWith()` is painfully long, suffering from repeated copy-pasta.
Truncated integer division can help us out.

The basic function you're computing by piecewise intervals is
`int gp = 1 + (mark - 1) / 10`.

---

## round to N display places

```
            std::cout << "Your CGPA is: " << cgpa << std::endl;
```

We probably want `printCGPA()` to round off that quotient
to some customary number of decimal places, perhaps four.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined what the CGPA should be, but this seems to be calculating a simple average, without using the credits allotted to a subject at all. As I understand it, (C)GPA is a weighted average with the credits being the weights, so we should have:

```
// somewhere above the loop
unsigned totalCredits = 0;
```

And then:

```
    // the loop begins
    // ...
    gradePointsSum += creditHour*calculator.getGradePointWith(mark);
    totalCredits += creditHour;
```

And instead of dividing by the number of subjects, we divide by the total credits:

```
printer.printCGPA(calculator.calculateCGPAWith(gradePointsSum, totalCredits));
```

(Then `gradePointsSum` should be `gradePointsWeightedSum` or something like that.)